# Jquery totalling from checkbox or without checkbox

Tags: jquery

I am calculating totals when a particular check boxes are being checked. The code is working fine. How can i view the grandtotal of all the item values if none of the checkboxes are checked.? Which means if i dont select any checkboxes, its should total the complete field vales and show in grandtotal. These values in the text boxes are not hardcoded, its generated after a calculation from another javascript function.

```
 $(function () {
 $("input[type='checkbox'").on("change", function () {
   recalcTotal();
 }).change();

function recalcTotal() {
var total12 = 0;
var checkedinput = $("input:checked");
var targetcheckboxes = checkedinput.length ? checkedinput : $("input:checkbox");
targetcheckboxes.each(function () {
    total12 += parseFloat($(this).next("input").val(),10) * 1;
});

$("#total12").val(total12.toFixed(3));

}
});
<input type="checkbox" name="values"/><input type="text" readonly value="100"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="200"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="300"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="400"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="500"/> <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="values" /><input type="text" readonly value="600"/> <br /><br />
<b>Grand Total:</b> <input type="text" id="total" readonly/> <br />
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z7L5y3s1/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/85v9xvnL/1/ ?

Comment: It look like it's working. Did you resolve?

Comment: @Arun. This script which i posted is working fine. But the problem here is the value of the text box is generated by another javascript function. Its basically a total of some other fields. If the value is there its works fine.

Comment: i have updated my question. i have put a fiddle the actual code. i didnt put this code its hefty. If you could run the fiddle its the first row after the value 786656.900, try to add some int like 20 or 21, the javascript calculates certain things and write a value to the last field that is margin. its has to take the total of this margin field and show the selected checkboxes or without checkboxes total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
function marginTotal(){

    var x = $('[name="gt[]"]:checked').length;
    if(x!=0) return;
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name="margin_for[]"]').each(function(){
        sum += +this.value;
    });
    $("#total12").val(sum);
}
```

Add all the values when no checkbox is selected else return.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/eb8gaon5/5/)

Comment: This script which i posted is working fine. But the problem here is the value of the text box is generated by another javascript function. Its basically a total of some other fields. If the value is there its works fine.

Comment: i have updated my question. i have put a fiddle the actual code. i didnt put this code its hefty. If you could run the fiddle its the first row after the value 786656.900, try to add some int like 20 or 21, the javascript calculates certain things and write a value to the last field that is margin. its has to take the total of this margin field and show the selected checkboxes or without checkboxes total.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you. Please try to explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: i will try to solve myself because i need to explain a lot on the working and formulaes given on the page. Anyways really thank you for the time. Thanx

Comment: Lets come on chat. Lets discuss your problem there.. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95539/regarding-issue-33799181

Comment: is it checking anything on page load?
i mean the new script?
This data iam saving to the mysql db using php. when i save it and come backs again in edit mode Grand total field its showing NaN. so that's why asked
You can also see it. wen u refresh the page. Grand Total is showing Nan
Is there any way i can hide it?